# Why do adverbials of place come before adverbials of time?

Tags: syntax, word-order

**He comes to class at 9 AM.** 
In the above sentence **to class**, the adverbial of place comes before **at 9 AM**, the adverbial of time.

Why is the below sentence wrong? 
**He comes at 9 AM to class."

Comment: In your example, "to class" is not an adverbial, in my opinion.  It's a complement of "comes".

Comment: This rule applies to English.  In German, time routinely comes before place, but German puts certain important elements at the end, so Greg Lee's explanation might hold water.

Comment: I wouldn't call that an adverbial of place - still it’s true that there’s a strong preference for the indication of place to come before the indication of time. It’s not an absolute rule and can be broken for emphasis, e.g. *you must go AT 9 AM to your designated pick-up point*.

Comment: I’m not sure if there is any deep reason for this particular order, although many other things seem to have preferred orders too – adjectives being the most obvious example. I can’t immediately come up with an example that would be liable to be misunderstood if the order deviated from the norm, so I doubt it’s for clarity.

Comment: Come to think of it, I don't think there's any particular preference between *we're meeting at 9 at the station* and *we're meeting at the station at 9*, so I think you have to sort out the parts of speech before you can really address the question of order.

Answer (score 0):

"come to class" is perceived as a verbal phrase. *to class* completements *come* which on it's own would be incomplete, and substandard in contrast to *arrived*.

You could as well say *He arrived at 9 am in class*, with both adverbial phrases.

This shows that your premisses is faulty and needs to be revised, when the remaining question *why do we say …* is too broad. Because we can, that's why. Can't we say *He come at 9 to class*? Hardly, that would be perceived as introducing a relative verbal phrase. * *What was he to class about? How long was he classing?* You might wonder. So, **the pressumed word order is not available, because the semantics of *to* are restricted in this position.** In other words, it is not idiomatic. That says nothing about the *Why* though.

---

PS: Indeed, I meant to argue elsewhere that *come to* is infact a lexical unit, but that's difficult. I'm concerned about German, in which seperable compounds like *zugehen*, *da geht es zu*, *zukommen*, *hinzukommen* offer more semantics to compare and extract an underlying representation of the surface form, that is not regularly recognized with the prepositional use: 1a) *Ich komme zu dem Haus* "I come to the house" 1b) *Das Haus kommt mir zu* "the house becomes mine". In thise usage *kommen* is proscribed for formal registers (and probably not only because of the vulgar connotation "to cum"), though *ankommen* "arive, venir" is formally regular (also seperable, *ich komme dort an* "I arrive there"). I want to argue that *come* cannot be simply reconstructed as *gwem- "to step"; on the one hand the participle prefix *ge-* requires furthervunderstanding to be excluded from the picture, though phonologicly it doesn't match well; yet, *ge-* from *kom- "with" well fits the semantics (cp. *convene*, *come-with*, *zukommen*, *mitcommen*, and derelict *commitative*, *allative*, *illative* cases, or rather aspects). Be that is it may, this Ansatz does depend on the notion of Proto-Indo-European preverbs and the difficult history of the Place-Words (cf. Brosch 2013). Therefore it has repeatedly been noted that preverbs were ordered rather freely, but are seen fixed in individual expressions. At that, I suppose, thethic and deictic, aspects play an important role (we know the place, only the time is new information). But, mirandering as I am, I have obviously no clear answer. Sorry. I merely hope to have shown that the question can be very difficult to treat with rigor.